# Unable to restrict Vault policy names in hcl template

Tags: hashicorp-vault, rbac, vault, hvac

I want to be able to create a policy that will allow to create kubernetes auth role and allow adding only a policy named `kuberneted/default`. I am using policy template as follows:

```
path "auth/kubernetes/role/{{identity.entity.aliases.auth_jwt_lll.metadata.project_id}}" {
  capabilities = ["read","delete", "list", "patch", "update","create"]
  
  allowed_parameters = {
    policies = ["kubernetes/default"]
    bound_service_account_names = []
    bound_service_account_namespaces = []
    ttl = []
  }
}
```

This is saved, so I do not thing there is a syntax issue, and also, I found this is working when I remove "kubernetes/default".

Anywyas, I get the error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/hvac/adapters.py", line 294, in _raise_for_error
    utils.raise_for_error(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/hvac/utils.py", line 41, in raise_for_error
    raise exceptions.VaultError.from_status(
hvac.exceptions.Forbidden: 1 error occurred:
    * permission denied
, on post https://my.local:443/v1/auth/kubernetes/role/2751
```

The auth token who holds this policy authenticated using Gitlab-ci ID Token which was jwt generated by Gitlab and it is configured with OIDC/jwt integration in vault. Although i do not believe this is the issue.